# Prism TabbedPage: Navigation back to a previous page does not work

Tags: xamarin, prism

I have the following page structure

- MainPage: TabbedPage

  - TabPage1: ContentPage

    - ContentPage1_1: ContentPage
  - TabPage2: ContentPage

This is the mainpage's xaml

```
<TabbedPage.Children>
  <NavigationPage Title="TabPage 1" IconImageSource="icon_about">
    <x:Arguments>
      <views:TabPage1/>
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
  <NavigationPage Title="TabPage 2" IconImageSource="icon_feed">
    <x:Arguments>
      <views:TabPage2/>
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

In TabPage1 we can navigate to another page ContentPage1_1. Thats the viewmodel's code for this

```
public DelegateCommand NavigateForwardCommand { get; set; }

public TabPage1ViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  NavigateForwardCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () =>
  {
    await navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(ContentPage1_1)}");
  });
}
```

> That navigation works

In ContentPage1_1 I try to navigate back to TabPage1. All my attemps fail.

Thats is what I tried.

```
public DelegateCommand NavigateBackwardCommand { get; set; }

public ContentPage1_1ViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  NavigateBackwardCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () =>
  {
    //await navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(ContentPage1_1)}");
    //await navigationService.NavigateAsync($"/../{nameof(TabPage1)}");
    //await navigationService.NavigateAsync($"/{nameof(MainPage)}/{nameof(NavigationPage)}/{nameof(TabPage1)}");
    //await navigationService.GoBackAsync();
    //await navigationService.GoBackToRootAsync();

  });
}
```

GoBackAsync does nothing. All the others loose either the tabs or the correct navigationbars.

> The arrow navigation in the navigationbar works!

How can I navigate back to the previous page within my tab?

Comment: You're using Prism but not using Prism's Navigation?

Comment: its a part of the [Prism Navigation Basics](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. In TabPage1ViewModel I changed the navigation to

```
public DelegateCommand NavigateForwardCommand { get; set; }
    
public TabPage1ViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
{
  NavigateForwardCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () =>
  {
    await navigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(ContentPage1_1)}");
  });
}
```

and removed the

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
```

attribute from the ContentPage1_1.xaml.

That was all.